# RTSP streaming with HTML5 video results in server died error (100,0) on Android

Tags: android, html, video-streaming, rtsp

I have a very simple HTML5 video streaming application for Android built with Phonegap. The device I am testing this is Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. The video does not stream at all. I see the following errors on the Eclipse Logcat window:

---

```
02-22 09:34:56.489: D/HTML5VideoView(6029): requestAudioFocus() called. proxy = Handler (android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy) {4176a958}
02-22 09:34:56.489: D/HTML5VideoView(6029): requested AudioFocus. videoView = android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullScreen@416fbd50
02-22 09:34:56.512: V/MotionRecognitionManager(6029):   .registerListenerEvent : success. listener count = 0->1, motion_sensors=1, listener=android.webkit.HTML5VideoView$1@416fbdd0
02-22 09:35:04.504: E/MediaPlayer(6029): internal/external state mismatch corrected
02-22 09:35:04.504: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(6029): media server died
02-22 09:35:04.504: W/AudioSystem(6029): AudioFlinger server died!
02-22 09:35:04.504: E/MediaPlayer(6029): error (100, 0)
02-22 09:35:04.551: E/MediaPlayer(6029): Error (100,0)
*******************************************************************************************

Here's my HTML code and Javascript code:

  <script src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
  <script>
     function onLoad(){
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
     }
     function onDeviceReady(){
          navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working!!");
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad();">
       <h1>Digital Home HTML5 Video Streaming Test</h1>
       <video preload="metadata" src="rtsp://nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/stream1" controls></video>
  </body>
```

---

I am wondering if this is because the server is sending a short intro video (or poster) before starting the actual stream which is being interpreted by the Galaxy tab as the server having died. I don't know what event I should add a listener for to handle this behavior. If I add a listener for ended event I may end up spinning in an infinite loop? The stream works fine on an iPad and another RTSP player that I downloaded from the Android market. What am I missing?

I am able to play the stream with VLC so the SDP description must be OK

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that Html 5 video don't support rtsp protocol at the moment. that simple.